# On Azure Portal, is it possible to disable Informational toast notifications only?

Tags: azure, notifications, azureportal

On Azure Portal, we started receiving some toast information notifications advertising the slot deployment feature on Azure WebApp.

Thoses notifications could be great when you don't know this feature. It's less great when you are already aware of this feature and can't disable this kind of notification.
It also seems that this notification is triggered each time a deployment is done on WebApps that does not use the slot deployment feature. You get spammed when you have a lot of WebApps, rendering those notifications useless :(

Each time you open the portal, you receive this spam :

[image: Notification spam]

The only way I found was to disable completely the toast notifications in the Azure portal settings :

[image: Azure portal settings]

That's not a good solution, we still want to get errors and warnings notifications.

Is there a way to disable only the App Service Advisor Informational notifications ?